# What "special" skins can be gifted in League?

Tags: league-of-legends

My little brother wants the Samsung White skins that are being given out on his birthday. I am wondering which skins can be gifted, if any. Could someone tell me which ones can be gifted?

Comment: Are you asking about the ones being given out for attending the Mid-Season Invitational?

Answer (score 1):

If the skin is purchasable currently, you can gift them as well including event specific skins except skins which are only obtainable by code (like PAX). If they are *limited skins* you can not gift them after the event deadline including as mystery gifts. Here is a [guide to skin types](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752944-Guide-to-Champion-Skin-Types#h1q5).